# c# Inserting int value into SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, insert, int

I want to insert some data into SQL table. But while inserting int no matter what I've tried I get error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value '@ID' to data type int.'

I even manually set ID to 1 simply to be 100 % sure it's int but still get that error

```
String query = "INSERT INTO table(dbo.table.ID, dbo.table.secondvar) 
VALUES ('@ID','@secondvar')";             
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        int ID = 1;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secondvar", tableModel.secondvar);    
                        connection.Open();
                        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the quotes around the values. The framework handles that already.

```
VALUES ('@ID','@secondvar')
```

should be

```
VALUES (@ID,@secondvar)
```

Comment: this answer is better, both values must be without semicolumns. I will mark this as answer after timeout elapse

Answer (score 1):

ID is an integer so it must not be between `''`:

Change this line:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO table(dbo.table.ID, dbo.table.secondvar) 
VALUES ('@ID','@secondvar')";
```

to this:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO table(dbo.table.ID, dbo.table.secondvar) 
VALUES (@ID,@secondvar)";
```

And [its better avoid using](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/egoldin/2014/07/02/ado-net-sql-parameters-avoid-addwithvalue-for-strings/) `AddWithValue` instead use it like:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO table(dbo.table.ID, dbo.table.secondvar) 
VALUES (@ID,'@secondvar')";             
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
 {
      int ID = 1;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@secondvar", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = somevalue; 
      //rest of the code
 }
```

Comment: Don't quote any values. Not even strings. The framework does that for you. That is the advantage of Prepared Statements.